# WordPress development workflow with version controlling

Tags: git, wordpress, ssh, workflow, hosting

I am currently managing a handful of freelance projects, mostly using WordPress (the clients preference). I develop the websites locally, running Apache/PHP/MySQL on my Mac. I version control these projects with Git.

Ideally, I want to be able to commit changes to a repository and then pull changes from there onto the server when they are ready to go live. This would be great, enabling me to have two versions of a website at any one time - development and live. For this I am guessing the server would need Git installed. However, I don't want to have to buy a VPS. Ideally, each client should have their own web space which they pay for on a monthly basis (or however they choose to pay).

So my question is, are there any small web hosting packages out there that offer this kind of thing? I need Git, and of course I'll need SSH to access Git. Taking into account that most of the time, the sites I make only get a few hits per day.

Also, is there any way to synchronise the MySQL databases here? If I am making changes to a website, I want to see them locally exactly how they will appear when they go live. Therefore it would be good to have all data in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://openshift.com They are a PaaS and have a PHP stack available. If you check their web site there is also a link to their github which has some examples available. One of them should be a Wordpress install. BTW, the Express version is free and usually good enough for low traffic sites.

Comment: Wandered in here hoping to find a good answer for this - I'm gonna look into it too - thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention this they offer a full git workflow for apps. Be they written in Ruby, PHP, Python, Perl, Java, ... you name it. Great guys and very helpful. I'm just a happy user there. No more :)